# Live php dockerize website getting "POST /index.php 404" and "POST /_ignition/execute-solution HTTP/1.1" 404 " in nginx part

Tags: php, docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose

I have a personal dockerized website built by php and runs in nginx server and also have configuration for ssl.
When i ran docker compose up after while suddenly i get 404 errors in docker compose logs:

```
nginx-note       | 136.*.*.* - - [22/Aug/2023:16:54:14 +0000] "GET /register HTTP/1.1" 200 11347 "https://mydomain/sessions" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
php-note         | 172.19.*.* -  22/Aug/2023:16:54:25 +0000 "POST /index.php" 200
nginx-note       | 136.*.*.* - - [22/Aug/2023:16:54:25 +0000] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 200 11990 "https://mydomain/register" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
php-note         | 172.19.*.* -  22/Aug/2023:16:55:26 +0000 "POST /index.php" 404
nginx-note       | 109.*.*.* - - [22/Aug/2023:16:55:27 +0000] "POST /_ignition/execute-solution HTTP/1.1" 404 7988 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
phpmyadmin-note  | 109.*.*.* - - [22/Aug/2023:16:55:27 +0000] "\x01\x01" 400 484 "-" "-"
php-note         | chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat /etc/ld.so.preload
php-note         | chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on /var/spool/cron
php-note         | chattr: Permission denied while setting flags on /etc/crontab
php-note         | bash: line 9: ufw: command not found
php-note         | bash: line 10: iptables: command not found
php-note         | bash: line 11: /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog: Read-only file system
php-note         | bash: line 12: /etc/sysctl.conf: Permission denied
php-note         | 172.19.*.* -  22/Aug/2023:16:55:27 +0000 "POST /index.php" 404
php-note         | main: line 236: pkill: command not found
php-note         | main: line 237: pkill: command not found
php-note         | main: line 238: pkill: command not found
```

and after that in login page my form post submiting fails like this:

[after hit the login button and submitin i get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrAuz.png)

I tried changing default.conf and specify index index.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used the root version of [docker config repo](https://github.com/aschmelyun/docker-compose-laravel/tree/permissions-fix-round-2) files and installed docker-compose on my virtual server for build and up commands.
I think the main issue was because i have not docker-compose installed on my server and was using the *docker compose up --build* instead of *docker-compose up --build*